# Port from C++/CLR to C# - MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, managed-c++, abi

I'm porting a *very* old library that we use here from C++/CLR (2.0 runtime, non-pure) to C#. This is a public API with a very large userbase, so I've been extremely careful about significant/meaningful ABI breakage (from [BitDiffer](https://github.com/bitdiffer/bitdiffer)):

[image: ABI is not broken]

The code in question is trivial: it copies a `SByte` from an internal byte buffer - but was implemented with a reintrepret cast over a pointer in C++/CLR (meaning that IJW was introduced).

I'm getting a `MissingMethodException` (note: not `TypeNotFoundException`). The assembly version, file version and runtime version [now] match. I can't determine why the metadata isn't matching. There is a runtime version mismatch (2.0 C++ assembly running on 4.0), so we are using `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`.

Any ideas on what I could try? Many thanks.

Comment: What does the IL say between the assemblies when run through ildasm/ILSpy? What you've got there is a C# declaration, not the IL declaration. There's *some* mismatch that prevents the one method reference from matching the method definition in the other assembly. This can be very subtle, like an indirect reference to another (framework) assembly with a version mismatch. Tweaking the activation policy might not be enough to fix that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I will have a look and post an update.